# Some Say It's Worth Two

Tags: rebus

The title has the clue; see if you can get this one:

```
HABIRDND
```

Comment: Hey BGM, are you going to mark this one correct? :)

Comment: Sorry!  I forgot; I marked it; thanks for the reminder.

Comment: To repay you, I'll upvote the question, since I forgot to do that when I answered it. :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that

> A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush!

Answer (score 10):

HABIRDND is actually

> HA**BIRD**ND --> A BIRD in the HA-ND ... is worth two in the bush!

Comment: He doesn't give any explanation how he got to his solution. People unfamiliar with this kind of riddle will probably be stumped without any hint that the String HABRDND is one word inside the other...

Comment: `HABIRDND = BUBIRDBIRDSH` would have been better, then.

Comment: @AdamDavis Or HABIRDND = BUTWOSH :-)

Comment: @Falco An even better construction!

Comment: I figured the title practically gives it away.